# Functional equation $f(x)=\frac 1T \sum_{t=1}^Tf(a+tx)$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, functions, functional-equations

I am dealing with the following functional equation:

$$ f(x)=\frac 1T \sum_{t=1}^Tf(a+tx)$$
where $a \in \mathbb{R}$ is a parameter. Is there a way to find a possible $f$ that satisfies the above equation?

EDIT: $f$ should be a cumulative distribution function, in particular it must be  non-decreasing and right-continuous.  I need a function that works for each $a$ and $f$ can depend on $T$.

Comment: Any constant will work.

Comment: I would need a non constant solution...

Comment: Can $f$ depend on $T$, or do you want one $f$ that works for all $T$?

Comment: I expect you have more conditions in mind.  For example, what about the function which is $0$ unless $x=na$ for some integer $n$ (and $f(na)=1$).  Is that one acceptable?

Comment: When you say "$a$ is a parameter", do you mean that you need examples for each possible value of $a$? Or do you need a single example that works for all values of $a$? And please answer Robert Israel's question as well.

Comment: I edited the question. I need a function that works for each $a$ and yes, it can depend on $T$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume $\lim_{y\to 0} f(y)$ exists:
$$ f(x)=\frac{f(a+x)+\dots+f(a+nx)}{n}=\frac{f(a+x)+\dots+f(a+nx)+f(a+(n+1)x)}{n+1} $$
$$ (n+1)(f(a+x)+\dots+f(a+nx))=n(f(a+x)+\dots+f(a+nx)+f(a+(n+1)x)) $$

$$ f(x)=\frac{f(a+x)+\dots+f(a+nx)}{n}=f(a+(n+1)x) $$
We get that $y=a+(n+1)x \implies x=\frac{y-a}{n+1}$
$$ f(x)=f(\frac{x-a}{n+1}) $$
Then by letting $n\to \infty$ we have
$$ f(x)=\lim_{y\to 0} f(y) $$
So the function is constant.